# Tables, Datatool: use "&" in true part of \DTLif

Tags: tables, datatool

I am trying to create a table with two different types of rows using a csv file.

The csv looks like this

```
Data1,Data2,Data3
Caption1,,
Value1,Value2,Value3
Value4,Value5,Value6
Caption2,,
Value8,Value9,Value10
.....
```

Every caption should use all three columns of the table, so I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \DTLloaddb{Database_Name}{Test.csv}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}
        \toprule
        a & b & c \\
        \midrule
        \DTLforeach{Database_Name}
            {\a=Data1,\b=Data2,\c=Data3}
            {
%-----------------------
                \DTLifnullorempty{\c}{\multicolumn{3}{c}{\a}}{\a & \b & \c}
%-----------------------
                \DTLiflastrow{}{\\}} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

but `\multicolumn` and `&` don't work if I use them in the condition. Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells in a LaTeX `tabular` are implicitly local groups. This will break many loop macros. A workaround is to compose the table in a token register first using the loop marco and output the token register to set the table afterwards:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\newtoks\tabletoks

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \DTLloaddb{Database_Name}{abc.csv}
    \centering
    \makeatletter
    \tabletoks={%
      \begin{tabular}{l c c}
      \toprule
      a & b & c \\
      \midrule
    }%
    \DTLforeach{Database_Name}{%
      \a=Data1,\b=Data2,\c=Data3%
    }{%
      \DTLifnullorempty{\c}{%
        \protected@edef\x{%
          \noexpand\multicolumn{3}{c}{\a}%
        }%
      }{%
        \protected@edef\x{\a & \b & \c}%
      }%
      \tabletoks\expandafter{\the\expandafter\tabletoks\x\\}%
    }%
    \tabletoks\expandafter{%
      \the\tabletoks
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
    \the\tabletoks
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\protected@edef` is used to expand the macros `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, before putting them into the token register.